# Django - Form not valid but no error

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Model:

```
class Session(models.Model):
    tutor = models.ForeignKey(User)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_time = models.DateTimeField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s - %s' % (self.tutor, self.start_time)
```

Form:

```
class SessionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Session
        exclude = ['tutor']
```

Testing:

```
>>> ses = Session.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> ses
<Session: Robert - 2012-03-22 13:00:00>
>>> form = SessionForm(instance=ses)
>>> form.is_valid()
false
>>> form.errors
{}
```

What's wrong ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You have not passed any data to the form, so it is not valid. The instance argument is not used to set the form data, just the initial data.

Comment: Ok I see. How can I set these initial values as actual ones ?

Comment: @PierredeLESPINAY: `form = SessionForm(data=ses)`

Comment: `form.is_valid()` => `'Session' object has no attribute 'get'`

Comment: Yes, @JordanReiter that won't work. You'd need to use something like the `model_to_dict` function in `django.forms.models`.

Comment: Actually I think I should do another question because I was searching a way to update certain values from a record

Comment: If using formsets, one can also `check form.none_form_errors`

Comment: You can set the initial values of a form as data by using the `data` attribute like this: `form(initial=initial_dict, data=initial_dict)`

Answer (score 7):

This is a humble attempt to provide a little background for [Daniel Roseman's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9909564).

As you can see in the [source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.0.x/django/forms/forms.py#L180), `BaseForm.is_valid()` does the following:

```
return self.is_bound and not self.errors
```

So, if `is_valid()` returns `False`, even though there are no errors, then `is_bound` must be `False`.

Now, the value for `is_bound` is assigned in `BaseForm.__init__()` ([source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.0.x/django/forms/forms.py#L72)):

```
self.is_bound = data is not None or files is not None
```

From the [forms documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/api/#bound-and-unbound-forms):

> A Form instance is either bound to a set of data, or unbound.
>
> - If it’s bound to a set of data, it’s capable of validating that data and rendering the form as HTML with the data displayed in the HTML.
> - If it’s unbound, it cannot do validation (because there’s no data to validate!), but it can still render the blank form as HTML.

Also note that `errors` is a property, which calls the `full_clean()` method ([source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.0.x/django/forms/forms.py#L175)), which does the actual validation.